# Empty azure subscription

Tags: azure-powershell

I am trying to run (from Powershell) this command:

**New-AzResourceGroup -Name RG1 -Location 'WestEurope'**

but I get an error message:

**New-AzResourceGroup : 'this.Client.SubscriptionId' cannot be null.**

Then I see that I cannot get the SubscriptionID with the command "**Get-AzSubscription**" ; it shows nothing.

So I run: **Get-AzContext -ListAvailable | FL**

and I see no Subscriptions ID either.

Here is a screenshot in case it may be useful:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the below command to **Get/Select** the **Azure Subscription**

```
#Get the Overall Subscription
Get-AzSubscription
#Select the specific subscription which you want to use.
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX

#After selecting Subscription create a resource 
New-AzResourceGroup -Name <Resource Group> -Location 'WestEurope'
```

##### Result

[image]

Comment: @paulO, did you able to log in to the Azure account using **az login**?. If yes make sure you have access to the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks DelliganeshS-MT

I already did what you kinldy mention, as noted in my question.

1. **Get-AzSubscription** - Nothing shows up
2. **Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX**

   I can not fill the XXXX-XXXX part due to what I indicate in point 1.

Anyway: Thanks a lot!